# SSIS Fails when run in job SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SSIS package that runs smoothly when I execute it from Visual Studio, but when I run it via SQL Server Job Task, it always fails to run and and throws this error:

> *Message Executed as user: **hidden**\**hidden**. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:23:40 AM 
>   Error: 2018-12-17 10:23:40.63     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Update
>   Report      Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:23:40 AM  Finished: 10:23:40 AM 
>   Elapsed:  0.594 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step
>   failed.*

I don't know the exact problem, the other jobs work normally, I guess it could be related to the fact that we just migrated to a new server, and the other jobs are old jobs that are mirrored from the old server.

This SSIS package contains scripted tasks which modify an excel file. This is normal in my company because we run many automation tasks, all of which have been working normally until now.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the user executing the package have enough rights to access(or modify) the excel file? When encountering issues stating 'it runs fine in VS but when SQL agent is used it fails', Most of the times, it has to do something with rights and accounts executing the packages. The detailed error log should give a better insight in the actual problem. Consider including it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer,

i have this script in my script task

> ```
> Declare Function EndTask Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
> Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" _
>        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
> Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" _
>        (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
> Declare Function SetLastError Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwErrCode As Integer) As IntPtr
> Public Sub EnsureProcessKilled(ByVal MainWindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Caption As String)
>     SetLastError(0)
>     ' for Excel versions <10, this won't be set yet
>     If IntPtr.Equals(MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero) Then
>         MainWindowHandle = FindWindow(Nothing, Caption)
>     End If
>     If IntPtr.Equals(MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero) Then
>         Exit Sub ' at this point, presume the window has been closed.
>     End If
>     Dim iRes, iProcID As Integer
>     iRes = GetWindowThreadProcessId(MainWindowHandle, iProcID)
>     If iProcID = 0 Then ' can’t get Process ID
>         If EndTask(MainWindowHandle) <> 0 Then Exit Sub ' success
>         Throw New ApplicationException("Failed to close.")
>     End If
>     Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
>     proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(iProcID)
>     proc.CloseMainWindow()
>     proc.Refresh()
>     If proc.HasExited Then Exit Sub
>     proc.Kill()
> End Sub
> ```

in this new server i dont have the rights to run this script to kill process, thats why the job always throw failed message for 0x00000001 error,

Thanks guys for trying to answer this problem

Comment: There should have been something in your logs that isolated this actual step